# C++ char* cannot be used as pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

i have problem with following code.

```
int main(){
   char* cptr = new char[100];
   *cptr[1] = 'A';
 }
```

It gives me error when i compile it in Visual C++ 2010:
"Operand of '*' must be a pointer".
But cptr is pointer.

Comment: `cptr[1]` is an array element, not a pointer to an element.  So you can say just `cptr[1] = 'A';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but `cptr[1]` is not - it's a `char`. That's what you're applying `*` to.

```
*cptr[1] == 
*  (cptr[1]) 
      | 
 this is a char
```

You could just write

```
char cptr[] = "A";
```

or use a `std::string`.

Comment: Note: he would get the same result when doing *(cptr+1)='A';

Comment: This is not correct. The expression `cptr[1]` is of type **reference** to a `char`.

Comment: Why  `char cptr[] = "A"`? I think it should be `char cptr[] = 'A';`

Comment: @IInspectable what about in C?

Comment: @IInspectable: this is not correct. There ain't no such thing as an expression of reference type, because "5p5 If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression." And in any case, `cptr[1]` is equivalent to `*(cptr+1)`, and according to 5.3.1p1 "If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is “`T`.” So `cptr[1]` was never a reference.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, the formal term is *lvalue*, but we know what was meant.

Comment: @haccks: try actually compiling it; that should convince you otherwise.

Comment: @Igor You just quoted *"an expression [...] has the type 'reference to `T`'"* but insist that *"there ain't no such thing"*.

Comment: @haccks: `char cptr[] = "A";` is equivalent to `char cptr[] = { 'A', 0 };`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: perhaps. Nevertheless, the statement by Luchian Grigore, which IInspectable took offense at and purported to correct, was in fact correct as originally written.

Comment: @BenVoigt; Never knew that before.

Comment: @IInspectable: there ain't no such thing for all practical intents and purposes, because the type is adjusted very early in the process of analysis, so the fact that the expression might have started as a reference is largely irrelevant. In any case, `cptr[1]` does not have a reference type, not even initially. 5.3.1p1 is for expressions like `f()` where `f` is a function declared to return a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
       char* cptr = new char[100];
       cptr[1] = 'A';
     }
```

This is the right manner to implement it.